# JdbcBatchItemWriter updating last record in database

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am facing an issue, the `JdbcBatchItemWriter` is picking the last record for update, I have created `ItemPrepartedStatementSetter` which is iterating through a Array of objects and setting up `preparedStatement`. Please provide any input, below is the code

XML :

```
<bean id="jdbcWriter"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
    <property name="sql"
              value="UPDATE XTABLE SET FLG = ? , LST_UPDT_DT =?
                     where CTGRY= ? AND TYPE =? AND SEQ_NBR =? AND SOURCE_KEY =?" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="itemPreparedStatementSetter">
        <bean class="com.batch.setter.XItemPrepartedStatementSetter" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Class

```
public class XItemPrepartedStatementSetter implements
        ItemPreparedStatementSetter<AggrPreference[]> {

    @Override
    public void setValues(X[] xArr, PreparedStatement preparedStatement)
            throws SQLException {
        for (int i = 0; i < xArr.length; i++) {
            X x = xArr[i];
            preparedStatement.setString(1, x.getFLG());
            preparedStatement.setTimestamp(2, x.getLST_UPDT_DT());
            preparedStatement.setString(3, x.getCTGRY());
            preparedStatement.setString(4, x.getTYPE());
            preparedStatement.setString(5, x.getSEQ_NBR());
            preparedStatement.setBigDecimal(6, x.getSOURCE_KEY());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, your question isn't exactly clear.  what exactly do you want you to do?  what's the error?

Comment: there are five records to be updated based on different SOURCE_KEY say SOURCE_KEY = 1,2,3,4,5. It only picking 5 the last one and updating 1 record in the database, ideally all the 5 rows should be updated

Answer (score 0):

Before all: why `setValues()` has `X[],PreparedStatement` and not `AggrPreference[],PreparedStatement` as signature?

You are using the `JdbcBatchItemWriter` in a wrong way because you are not perform an update for every element in `X[] arr` but only for the last one (and this is the cause you get updated only the last element).
If your domain object is correct (the `X[] arr`) you have to write a custom `ItemWriter` that loop through object and use the real `JdbcBatchItemWriter` to perform write one element at time.
If your intention was to write each X as single item your domain object is wrong and should be a single `X` object and not an array.
According to those modifications you have to change `XItemPrepartedStatementSetter` as

```
public class XItemPrepartedStatementSetter implements ItemPreparedStatementSetter<AggrPreference> {
  @Override
  public void setValues(AggrPreference x, PreparedStatement preparedStatement) throws SQLException {...}
}
```

Object returned from `ItemProcessor` must be of type `AggrPreference` and SB will write each chunk of object using your new configuration.

I hope I was clear, English is not my native language.

Comment: My bad , AggrPreference and X are same object

Comment: doesn't matter, the solution is teh same: don't use a X[] but a single X in diamond operator and all should works fine.

Comment: Changing X[] to X process a single record which is the last record in the list